# Java Selenium Explicit wait not working while thread sleep does

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to recreate some browser automation I have already created in VBA in anticipation of the retiring of Internet Explorer.

I have decided to try it first in Java using Selenium Webdriver.

Here is my code with comments to explain why I do some stuff that seems dumb and what behavior I am seeing when trying to run:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","[Gecko location]\\geckodriver.exe");
        
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        
        driver.get("[target url]");

        driver.findElement(By.name("[Username Element]")).sendKeys("[Username]");

        driver.findElement(By.name("[Password Element]")).sendKeys("[Password]");

        driver.findElement(By.name("[Login Button]")).click();
        
        //At this point, the login page gets closed. A popup happens, it closes, then another window opens and I am logged into the website.

        Set <String> allwindowhandles= driver.getWindowHandles();

        String windowhandle= driver.getWindowHandle();

        Iterator<String> iterator = allwindowhandles.iterator();
        
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String ChildWindow = iterator.next();
                if (!windowhandle.equalsIgnoreCase(ChildWindow)) {
                driver.switchTo().window(ChildWindow);
                WebElement text = driver.findElement(By.id("[Next element I want to click]"));
                //For what its worth, this next part was in a code sample I found, but doesn't get printed in the terminal. Will need to understand what is going on here better at some point.
                System.out.println("Heading of child window is " + text.getText());
                }

        }

        driver.findElement(By.id("[Next element I want to click]")).click();

       //After clicking, the next element I want to click is in an Iframe inside and Iframe.
       Thread.sleep(5000);

       driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='[First Iframe]']")));

       driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='[Second Iframe]']")));

       driver.findElement(By.id("[Element in Iframe in Iframe]")).click();

       //In all 3 scenarios (No wait, implicit wait, explicit wait), this message publishes to terminal.

       System.out.println("Starting wait");

       //The below commented out code for some reason causes the following click not to occur

       //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(10));

       //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("[Next element that is located in same iframe inside iframe]")));

       //Without this pause, the button doesn't get clicked. With this pause, the button gets clicked

       Thread.sleep(5000);
       
       //In all 3 scenarios (No wait, implicit wait, explicit wait), this message publishes to terminal immediately after 'starting wait', almost instantaneously for the explicit wait, after 5 seconds for the implicit wait.)

       System.out.println("Trying to click.");

       driver.findElement(By.id("[Next element that is located in same iframe inside iframe]")).click();

    }
}
```

My issue is that the website is pretty unreliable with load times. If I were to do implicit waits all the way through, I would need to set them all to 15-30 seconds to make sure they the target element is there every time. That adds up.

Anyone see anything glaring that would make my Explicit wait not work? My IDE isn't giving me any errors when I try to run. Only cautions me about unused imports when I comment out the explicit wait.

Comment: use expected condition of frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt.... that may help.  Implicit waits are just like Explicit in that they will wait only as long as is necessary for the element to appear.  DO NOT mix them.  Use one or the other.  Neither Implicit or Explicit waits are the same as a sleep... they are polling loops that wait until a condition evaluates to true or the timeout period is reached.  Implicit waits are set globally... (only set it once.)  Visibility doesn't necessarily mean clickable... (use elementToBeClickable)

Comment: Implicit wait only checks for existence methinks... (not really sure cause I always use explicit waits... )

Comment: I have no reason to think it, but I feel like "Thread.Sleep()" is gumming up the works, but I dont fully understand the iterator chunk of code, so I dont understand how I would incorporate an explicit wait into that chunk of code. If I can get rid of the first Thread.sleep i could see if that would make a "frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt" work instead of the next one. Guess my next step is to google dive to learn to understand the iterator...

Comment: It's possible the element is there, visible, but not clickable yet.  Which is why it's failing.  Try/catch your selenium method calls to get an idea of what exceptions are thrown besides timeout.